# GitLab Runner - ERROR: Failed to remove network for build

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: vibraniumcore/gcc-cmake-boost-mysqlcon
#image: gitlab/dind

stages:
  - test
  - build

Run Tests:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - c++
  script:
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake ..
    - cmake --build . --target VibraniumCoreTests
    - cd ./Tests
    - ./VibraniumCoreTests

Build VibraniumCore:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - c++
  script:
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake ..
    - cmake --build .

Build AuthServer:
  stage: build
  tags:
  - c++
  script:
    - cd Scripts
    - ./build_authserver.sh

Build WorldServer:
  stage: build
  tags:
  - c++
  script:
    - cd Scripts
    - ./build_worldserver.sh
```

When I try to run my pipeline I get this error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.1.1 (6fbc7474)
  on GCC-CMAKE HdBd6UX6
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:35
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.25/info: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer (docker.go:894:4s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.25/info: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer (docker.go:894:10s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.25/info: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer (docker.go:894:10s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): error during connect: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.25/info: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer (docker.go:894:10s)
```

Any idea why I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: How do you configure gitlab CI, maybe gitlab can not join docker endpoint (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#register-a-runner-that-uses-the-docker-executor) and that's not cause by your pipeline script.

Comment: re-trying it seems to make it work, sometimes

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have your runner setup with `executor="docker"`, you may encounter the `"ERROR: Failed to remove network for build"` error if you have not installed docker on your machine hosting the runner.

In Ubuntu, try:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

And then re-run the pipeline.

Comment: This solution works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22, thank you!

Comment: This didn't help for me in Ubuntu 22.10. The problem could be that the image is not specified instead (that partially solved this error message for me).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
I used "sudo gitlab-runner register" instead of "gitlab-runner register" and in my case the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If docker is installed but you are still getting the error then you need to give the user permissions to use docker:

```
usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an image to you job.

```
run_tests:
 stage: test
 image: vibraniumcore/gcc-cmake-boost-mysqlcon # add this line here
 tags:
  - c++
 ...
```

---

Or use default image:

```
default:   # add this line here
 image: vibraniumcore/gcc-cmake-boost-mysqlcon

run_tests:
 stage: test
 ...
```

Answer (score -4):

This issue is due to the executor="docker" you are using in gitlab runner. try to change to "shell" or "ssh"